# How to implement fullcalendar.io Scheduler using visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript-remoting

I got ahold of [FullCalendarScheduler](https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/) library. I have been successful getting the standard FullCalendar working on Visualforce but it didnt suit my requirement. I am trying to use the Scheduler variant of this but im getting a blank page and no messages on debug. Has someone actually implemented this on salesforce that can assist. Below is my code

Controller:

```
public class CTRL_EventScheduler {
    public string eventsJSON {get;set;}

    //The calendar plugin is expecting dates is a certain format. We can use this string to get it formated correctly
    static String dtFormat = 'EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z';

    @RemoteAction
    public static string eventdata(){
        calEvent[] events = new calEvent[]{};
        for(Event evnt: [SELECT Subject, isAllDayEvent, StartDateTime, EndDateTime FROM Event WHERE RecordTypeId =: DAL_Event.RT_WORK_ORDER_EVENT.Id]){
            DateTime startDT = evnt.StartDateTime;
            DateTime endDT = evnt.EndDateTime;

            calEvent myEvent = new calEvent();
            myEvent.title = evnt.Subject;
            myEvent.allDay = evnt.isAllDayEvent;
            myEvent.startString = startDT.format(dtFormat);
            myEvent.endString = endDT.format(dtFormat);
            myEvent.url = '/' + evnt.Id;
            myEvent.className = 'event-personal';
            events.add(myEvent);
        }

        string jsonEvents = JSON.serialize(events);
        jsonEvents = jsonEvents.replace('startString','start');
        jsonEvents = jsonEvents.replace('endString','end');

        return jsonEvents;
    }

    // Class to hold calendar event data
    public class calEvent {
        public String title {get;set;}
        public Boolean allDay {get;set;}
        public String startString {get;set;}
        public String endString {get;set;}
        public String url {get;set;}
        public String className {get;set;}
    }
}
```

My page:

```
<apex:page id="EventScheduler" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" controller="CTRL_EventScheduler">
    <!--<link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.fullCalendarScheduler,'lib/fullcalendar.min.css')}" rel='stylesheet' />-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.css" />
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/scheduler.css" />-->
    <link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.fullCalendarScheduler,'/scheduler.css')}" rel='stylesheet' />

    <!--<script href="{!URLFOR($Resource.fullCalendarScheduler,'lib/moment.min.js')}"></script>-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
    <!--<script href="{!URLFOR($Resource.fullCalendarScheduler,'lib/jquery.min.js')}"></script>-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <!--<script href="{!URLFOR($Resource.fullCalendarScheduler,'lib/fullcalendar.min.js')}"></script>-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <script href="{!$Resource.fullCalendarSchedulerJS}"></script>

    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getEventData() {                         // records are retrieved from soql database
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                    '{!$RemoteAction.CTRL_EventScheduler.eventdata}',  // controller and method names
                    function(result, event){
                        if (event.status) {
                            evt =  JSON.parse(result);
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({       // html element and library name
                                events: evt
                            })
                        } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                            console.log(event.message);
                        } else {
                            console.log(event.message);
                        }
                    },
                    {escape: false}
            );
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            getEventData();
        });
    </script>

    </body>
</apex:page>
```

I thought maybe my library wasnt working so commented it out and made changes but still no outpu. Please assist

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page is missing an element with the Id calendar:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

so `$('#calendar')` will evaluate to an empty collection and nothing will appear.

I'd also recommend a bit more debug output to check that the data is being fetched:

```
console.log(result);
var evt =  JSON.parse(result);
console.log('parsed');
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: evt
});
```

Comment: are you able to help me with a fullCalendarScheduler issue. I posted a new question on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41828782/fullcalendar-scheduler-beginner-setup-how-to-display-and-group-events-by-resour

Comment: @NelsonChisoko Sorry not familiar with that library.